# SQL aggregation using group by of columns one by one

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregation

**Scenario:**

Below is my table.

```
+-------+-----------+--------+--------+
|col2   |col3       |col4    |col5    |
+-------+-----------+--------+--------+
|    1.0|          2|       a|      a1|
|    1.0|          1|       a|      a2|
|    1.0|          2|       b|      a3|
|    2.0|          1|       a|      a1|
|    2.0|          1|       a|      a2|
+-------+-----------+--------+--------+
```

I need to get the aggregated result as below.

```
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----+
|col2   |col3       | field_name|field_value|count|
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----+
|    2.0|          1|   col3    |          1|    2|
|    1.0|          1|   col3    |          1|    1|
|    1.0|          2|   col3    |          2|    2|
|    2.0|          1|   col4    |          a|    2|
|    1.0|          1|   col4    |          a|    1|
|    1.0|          2|   col4    |          a|    1|
|    1.0|          2|   col4    |          b|    1|
|    1.0|          1|   col5    |         a2|    1|
|    1.0|          2|   col5    |         a1|    1|
|    1.0|          2|   col5    |         a3|    1|
|    2.0|          1|   col5    |         a1|    1|
|    2.0|          1|   col5    |         a2|    1|
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----+
```

**Implemented Solution:**

I implemented the solution by creating three different tables[T1, T2, T3]. 
And then for each table, I created  [rowset1, rowset2, rowset3] programmatically to combine all into a single table

```
select col2, col3, col3, count(*) from calc group by col2, col3;
T1 :
|col2   |col3       |col3       |count|
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----+
|    2.0|          1|          1|    2|
|    1.0|          1|          1|    1|
|    1.0|          2|          2|    2|
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----+

rowset1 = [[2.0,1,col3,1,2,18000], [1.0,1,col3,1,1,18000], [1.0,2,col3,2,2,18000]]

select  col2, col3,  col4, count(*) from calc group by col2, col3, col4;
T2:
+-------+-----------+--------+-----+
|col2   |col3       |col4    |count|
+-------+-----------+--------+-----+
|    2.0|          1|       a|    2|
|    1.0|          1|       a|    1|
|    1.0|          2|       a|    1|
|    1.0|          2|       b|    1|
+-------+-----------+--------+-----+
rowset2 = [[2.0,1,col4,a,2,18000], [1.0,1,col4,a,1,18000], [1.0,2,col4,a,1,18000],[1.0,2,col4,b,1,18000]]

select col2, col3, col5 , count(*) from calc group by col2, col3, col5;
T3:
+-------+-----------+--------+-----+
|col2   |col3       |col5    |count|
+-------+-----------+--------+-----+
|    1.0|          1|      a2|    1|
|    1.0|          2|      a1|    1|
|    1.0|          2|      a3|    1|
|    2.0|          1|      a1|    1|
|    2.0|          1|      a2|    1|
+-------+-----------+--------+-----+

rowset3 = [1.0,2,col5,b,1,18000], [1.0,1,col5,a2,1,18000], [1.0,2,col5,a1,1,18000], [1.0,2,col5,a3,1,18000], [2.0,1,col5,a1,1,18000], [2.0,1,col5,a2,1,18000]]
```

**Problem**:

How can I achieve the same in SQL without an overhead of creating rowset1,2,3 and combining it into a single table?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: it's generic to all but I have tagged it.

Comment: I believe you are looking for the pivot function

Comment: @Singh . . . Not at all.  You are running queries.  Those queries are running against a database.  The database has capabilities that differ from EVERY OTHER database that is out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to do three aggregations in one.  One method is to use `cross join` to bring in the information to distinguish each aggregation:

```
select col2, col3, field_name,
       (case when field_name = 'col3' then col3
             when field_name = 'col4' then col4
             when field_name = 'col5' then col5
        end) as field_value,
       count(*) as cnt
from t cross join
     (select 'col3' as field_name union all
      select 'col4' as field_name union all
      select 'col5' as field_name
     ) f
group by col2, col3, field_name, field_value
order by field_name, col2 desc, col3;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6fbed983271e14a27a0c9c0af68fabde) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: @Singh . . . (1) I added a db<>fiddle and an `order by` to the query.  (2) This produces EXACTLY the same result set in your question.  This question is answered.